# How do I change one icon into two different icons in flutter?

Tags: javascript, java, android, flutter, dart

How do I change one icon into two different icons in flutter? This is what I have so far.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final WebPage currentPage = webPages[currentPageIndex];

  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: WebView(
        initialUrl: currentPage.url,
        javaScriptMode: JavaScriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: _controller.complete,
      ),
    ),


    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTapNavigation,
        currentIndex: currentPageIndex,
        items: webPages
            .map((webPage) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.school), title: Text(webPage.title)))
            .toList()),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how i once implemented switching icons based on a bool value

```
bool _newNotification = false;
  Tab(
            icon: _newNotification
                ? Icon(
                    Icons.directions_boat,
                    size: 28,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                : Icon(
                    Icons.notifications,
                    size: 28,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
),
```